# Regex and raw string literals

Tags: regex

I've been reading through all the various questions on raw string literals and escape characters, and I'm still confused - I can't find an answer in simple enough terms for me to understand...

I understand that prefixing a string with "r" treats escape characters as literals, so for example:

```
my_string = r"\n"
```

gives the literal string "\n" as opposed to the newline feed which you get from

```
my_other_string = "\n"
```

However, if I then use regex to match this string literal it doesn't work:

```
match = re.search(r"\n", my_string)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Show an example of the string you think should match.

Comment: Something of interest, maybe: `re.search(r'\n', '\n')` matches :P

Comment: That's confused me more (!) - surely that's trying to match a literal \n with a newline feed, which shouldn't work...

Comment: The long and short of it is: the `r` is enough to escape it for python. You have to escape it again for re. `re.search(r'\\n',\n')`

Comment: Thanks, so given the above definition of my_string, match = re.search(r"\\n", my_string) should produce a match.

Answer (score 0):

```
match = re.search(r"\\n", my_string)
```

You need to escape `\` as in `my_string` you have defined `raw string` .So python will not take it as 1 character `\n` but `2` characters `\` and `n`.So you need to use `\\` to match `\`.

Comment: the `r` is sufficient to escape it for python. You just need to escape it *again* for `re`, which is why you see people using raw strings a lot for re, because typing two backslashes for everything gets tiring real fast.

Comment: @NightShadeQueen yes that's becos of `r` `\n` will treated as `2` characters and not `1`.So `re` will not be able to match `\`.For that we need `\\`.